# Web Audio API audio editor saving edited clip back onto web server

Tags: save, editor, trim, web-audio-api, clip

I am making a drum machine and have implemented a recording function using recorderJS library. The problem as you may expect is limited functionality in terms of not been able to edit the recorded clips. So my question is if I was to implement an audio editor that allows the user to trim the clip, how would I go about saving the edited clip back onto the web server?

Is this even possible using Web Audio API?

Many Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [WebAudio *offline* context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) to render your edited audio to a buffer you can transmit to the server.

Comment: You can easily edit the recorded clip using some UI for the markings and clipping the appropriate data from the `AudioBuffer` using the `getChannelData` method. I think a library like waves.js might help you there. http://ircam-rnd.github.io/waves/ui/#ui-segment

Comment: Then you'll have to somehow convert the file into say a wav file and send it to the sever. You can look at this for that. https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/pcmdata.js/

Answer (score 2):

The web audio API doesn't do this for you; you need a back end server that can accept uploads.  You'll also probably want to re-encode the audio data (as a WAV, MP3, OGG, etc.)